# Unable to Create "Spring Template Project" in STS-3.6.4

Tags: spring-tool-suite

I am using

1.Eclipse Luna 4.4.0

2.Jdk 1.8.0

3.Spring tool Suite 3.6.4

I wanted to Create **"Spring Template Project"** but though I have installed STS-3.6.4 from Eclipse MarketPlace when I go to "File->New->Project",at their also when I search for **Spring Template Project' no any such option coming**.
only these options are coming:Create New

a.Spring Getting Started Content

b.Spring Bean Configuration File

c.Spring Bean Definition

d.Spring Project

e.Spring Roo Project

d.Spring Starter Project

e.Spring Web Flow Definition File

So i downloaded separate "SPRING TOOL SUITE™ Eclipse-based development" from spring.io/tools of 400MB.

But Still for creating new Project same menu coming.

I required STS for creating ***Java Spring Rest service ( jQuery - Ajax - JSON)*** (Web Service with Web Application using Ajax as shown in https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4fYCp_rjA3A)

So which Plugin I should download ? or How can i create such Spring Template Project using above menu I am getting ?

These are Error Log i got when i added STS in eclipse

https://www.dropbox.com/sh/48h5i1gfl62xq6b/AABO_HC3-C1_Avgs4eKa4_Cha?dl=0

Comment: Not really an answer to your question, but maybe it might help. You could try using this guide:https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/ instead of template projects (templates are quite old and not much supported anymore). You can also import the code of that "rest service guide" using the STS "Import Getting Started Content" wizard, as explained here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/sts/ Then you can use it as starting point for your own code.

Answer (score 0):

What is referred to as the 'Spring Template project wizard' is likely the old 'New Spring Project' wizard. You can open it via menu "File >> New >> Spring Project" from the "Spring" Perspective in STS.